# WordPress 4.9.8 Trying to add filename over image in Media Browser

Tags: uploads, media-library, media-modal

Need to add filenames of images in the media browser (not the media library, the browser when you are adding media to a post or page). I used this snippet to do that but it no longer works in WordPress 4.9.8

The code I have:

```
    add_action( 'in_admin_footer', 'my_wrap_media_template_callback', 10, 0 );

    function wp_print_media_templates_wrapper() {
ob_start();
wp_print_media_templates();
$output = ob_get_clean();

// Finding the correct spot to insert
$to_find = '
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <div class="centered">
            <img src="{{ data.size.url }}" draggable="false" />
        </div>
    </div>';
// HTML that will render filename
$to_add = '
            <div class="filename">
                <div>{{ data.filename }}</div>
            </div>';
$output = str_replace( $to_find, $to_find . $to_add, $output );
echo $output;
}
```

Image for reference of what I'm trying to do:

[image]